# Undestanding NSZombie log

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management, exc-bad-access, instruments, nszombie

I'm trying to track a exc-bad-access. I have run Instruments with NSZombie enabled, I get this error log when the app crashes. There is a UIView which is autoreleased four times, but before the autoreleased pool is drained it just has a reference count of 3 so int ends with   -1 reference count.

I am not sending any autoreleased messages myself, so how can I solve this?

```
#   Category    Event Type  RefCt   Timestamp   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Caller
0   UITextView  Malloc  1   00:09.478.888   0x80c2920   448 UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
1   UITextView  Retain  2   00:09.492.814   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITextView resignFirstResponder]
2   UITextView  Autorelease     00:09.492.822   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITextView resignFirstResponder]
3   UITextView  Retain  3   00:09.494.396   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
4   UITextView  Retain  4   00:09.494.400   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _replaceObject:withObject:]
5   UITextView  Release 3   00:09.494.403   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
6   UITextView  Retain  4   00:09.494.407   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
7   UITextView  Release 3   00:09.494.448   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
8   UITextView  Autorelease     00:09.494.845   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
9   UITextView  Retain  4   00:09.494.848   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:]
10  UITextView  Retain  5   00:09.495.215   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
11  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.495.230   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
12  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.495.241   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
13  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.495.255   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:]
14  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.495.277   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIView initWithCoder:]
15  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.495.325   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
16  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.499.036   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
17  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.499.306   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
18  UITextView  Retain  7   00:09.499.325   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
19  UITextView  Release 6   00:09.499.336   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver _decodeArrayOfObjectsForKey:]
20  UITextView  Retain  7   00:09.499.358   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSArray(NSArray) initWithCoder:]
21  UITextView  Release 6   00:09.499.385   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:]
22  UITextView  Retain  7   00:09.499.511   0x80c2920   0   Proyecto3   -[EventoDetailViewControllerClass setNombreTextView:]
23  UITextView  Release 6   00:09.499.681   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver dealloc]
24  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.499.747   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver dealloc]
25  UITextView  Release 4   00:09.499.762   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver dealloc]
26  UITextView  Release 3   00:09.499.817   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSKeyedUnarchiver dealloc]
27  UITextView  Release 2   00:09.499.880   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIRuntimeConnection dealloc]
28  UITextView  Retain  3   00:09.534.891   0x80c2920   0   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
29  UITextView  Release 2   00:09.534.895   0x80c2920   0   QuartzCore  CALayerLayoutIfNeeded
30  UITextView  Retain  3   00:09.607.480   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
31  UITextView  Retain  4   00:09.607.947   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setView:]
32  UITextView  Retain  5   00:09.607.951   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setGestureView:]
33  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.608.655   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch view]
34  UITextView  Autorelease     00:09.608.658   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouchesEvent _clearViewForTouch:]
35  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.608.661   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setView:]
36  UITextView  Release 4   00:09.608.666   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setGestureView:]
37  UITextView  Release 3   00:09.608.807   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
38  UITextView  Retain  4   00:09.609.307   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setView:]
39  UITextView  Retain  5   00:09.609.311   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setGestureView:]
40  UITextView  Retain  6   00:09.725.677   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch view]
41  UITextView  Autorelease     00:09.725.680   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouchesEvent _clearViewForTouch:]
42  UITextView  Release 5   00:09.725.684   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setView:]
43  UITextView  Release 4   00:09.725.688   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UITouch(UITouchInternal) setGestureView:]
44  UITextView  Release 3   00:09.725.839   0x80c2920   0   Foundation  -[NSAutoreleasePool release]
45  UITextView  Zombie  -1  00:11.383.459   0x80c2920   0   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _invalidateSubviewCache]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Instruments to profile Leaks, it's best to ignore any leaks that are shown as attributed to Apple libraries. The Leaks to investigate are those show to originate in your app's code.

Objects that are autoreleased are released when the pool is drained. If you haven't created any of your own objects that are autoreleased, then the only autoreleased objects must be Apple's own, e.g.`[NSString string]`.

I assume you have already run the Analyzer and resolved all issues highlighted? If not, that's the first step.

Next, look at the line where the`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`occurs. It*may*offer a clue as to the offending object. Chances are that - or some other - object are being released prematurely, or alternatively you have not retained them sufficiently.

When that happens, at some point the runtime will deallocate them. Trying to access them causes the dreaded`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Here's the link to Lou Franco's explanation on`EXC_BAD_ACCESS`and how to track it down:

[Understanding EXC_BAD_ACCESS](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html)

Comment: Although I finally managed to get it myself I mark your answer as solved since Analyzer is what lead me to get the zombie.